# Handle case where a function is called without parameters?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm doing a coding exercise where one of the tests calls a method `get_count()` that is defined below. One of the tests calls `get_count()` without passing any arguments to it. I want the function to still return `result = {'vowels':0, 'consonants':0}` even if the function is called without any arguments. Is there a way to do this in python?

```
def get_count(words):
    result = {'vowels':0, 'consonants':0}
    if not words:
        return result
    if type(words) is not str:
        return result
    for letter in words.lower():
        if letter in 'aeiou':
            result['vowels'] += 1
        elif letter.isalpha():
            result['consonants'] += 1
    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a default argument:

```
def get_count(words=None):
    result = {'vowels':0, 'consonants':0}
    if not words:
        return result
    if type(words) is not str:
        return result
    for letter in words.lower():
        if letter in 'aeiou':
            result['vowels'] += 1
        elif letter.isalpha():
            result['consonants'] += 1
    return result
```

Conveniently, you already had an `if not words` in there.  `None` has a boolean value of `False`, so if `words` is not given, that `if` statement will be executed.

Answer (score 3):

This is where you would use a [default function argument](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

```
def get_count(words=None):
    result = {'vowels':0, 'consonants':0}
    if not words:
        return result
    if type(words) is not str:
        return result
    for letter in words.lower():
        if letter in 'aeiou':
            result['vowels'] += 1
        elif letter.isalpha():
            result['consonants'] += 1
    return result
```

Generally for the case where you just want to return default results, you want to use `None` as the default value. In the case where your function could run with out passing the argument, you can use any value you want as the default. Just be careful about using a mutable object as the value, because it can have some interesting consequences. Specifically, the object is only created when the function is first defined, so every time you call the function, it will persist.

Here's an example:

```
def mutable(x, y=[]):
    y.append(x)
    return y

print(mutable(1)) # Prints [1]
print(mutable(2)) # Prints [1, 2]
```

Comment: My favorite example of unwanted behavior when using default values is the first 'interview question' listed here: https://www.toptal.com/python/interview-questions

Answer (score 0):

Given `words` is meant to be a string you can use a default argument of an empty string `''`, then you can simplify your code. BTW a common idiom in python is [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) and is generally used instead of LBFL:

```
def get_count(words=''):
    result = {'vowels':0, 'consonants':0}
    try:
        for letter in words.lower():
            if letter in 'aeiou':
                result['vowels'] += 1
            elif letter.isalpha():
                result['consonants'] += 1
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return result
```

And if you want to totally over-engineer it you can use the `partition` `itertools` recipe:

```
import itertools as it

def partition(pred, iterable):
    t1, t2 = it.tee(iterable)
    return filter(pred, t1), it.filterfalse(pred, t2)

def get_count(words=''):
    p = partition(lambda c: c in 'aeiou', filter(str.isalpha, words.lower()))
    return {k: sum(1 for _ in v) for k, v in zip(['vowels', 'consonants'], p)}

>>> get_count('Hello, World!')
{'consonants': 7, 'vowels': 3}
```

*Sorry I was bored*